# OpenLayers - avoid Parameter 'width' contains unacceptable value error

Tags: openlayers, wms, getmap

I am using [`ol.source.ImageWMS`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_ImageWMS-ImageWMS.html) to insert layers into a web map from [this WMS](http://www.cartografia.regione.lombardia.it/ArcGIS10/services/wms/dusaf21/MapServer/WMSServer?service=wms&request=getcapabilities).

However, I am receiving `Parameter 'width' contains unacceptable value error` error if my screen + resolution is too high due to the WMS `MaxWidth` parameter being `2048`. If I decrese the size of my window then the GetMap request is fine because the width value is lower than the limit.

Is there a way to make it work regardless of this limitation?

I don't have access to the WMS server, so changing the `MaxWidth` is not feasible.

Comment: Switch to WMS version 1.1.1

Comment: @nmtoken According to this docs (http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/basics.html#differences-between-wms-versions) there does not seem to be very much difference between 1.1.1 and 1.3.0 so I'm thinking that maybe I could have 1.1.1 as defalut version for my client app when requesting for WMS if this fixes this problem. Would you reccomend doing so? (it's just a development application I am doing for learning purposes ;) ) https://github.com/umbe1987/shire

Comment: Well, the version 1.1.1 GetCapabilities response doesn't specify any MaxWidth, and the WMS 1.1.1 OGC specification document doesn't have such a setting, (whilst the WMS 1.3.0 spec does), so...   It's possible that it was fixed before and WMS 1.3.0 allows the provider to set it, but possibly worth a punt

Comment: @nmtoken thanks! Will test it and tell you if it works (also considering some tests with other wms services and the consequences of setting 1.1.1 as default version)

Comment: @nmtoken mmm, it does not seem to have fixed the problem. Now I am creating the ol.source.ImageWMS with params:{'VERSION':'1.1.1.'} and indeed it is requesting the GetMap with this version. However, I still can see from the dev console that a 'WIDTH' parameter is still passed from OL, if whose value is greater than 2048 now the response is not the same error I posted above as in version 1.3.0, but a strange long alphanumeric string. Still, no image is shown.

Comment: I think the most elegant way is to print the error (Exception) I receive from the WMS server somewhere in my application. Do you know how to do that? I mean, as long as OL API handles the GetMap requests, I don't see how I could catch the Exception response from the WMS when (e.g.) width is too large.

Comment: Nevermind, found it myself: it was a matter of using the event `imageloaderror` as described in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_ImageWMS-ImageWMS.html and as explained (e.g.) in https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/168280/9518.

Comment: Ok, sorry to post again, maybe I'll open a new question, but, how would I log the error itself (i.e. Parameter 'width' contains unacceptable value error). Is it possible?

Comment: If the specification doesn't mention any such restriction, (and I just double checked, and it doesn't), and the GetCapabilities document response doesn't have such a setting, then the error is with the server software, which is in this case ArcGIS, so you would need to log the issue with ESRI.

Comment: See also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232399/limit-imagewms-request-size  For a working example of the "Stretch" method see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687274/requested-wms-image-width-exceeds-the-server-maximum/56839194#56839194